# import cv2 dll load failed: the specified module could not be found

Tags: python, opencv

I create python 3.7 environment in `anaconda2`, and install `opencv` by `conda install -c conda-forge opencv`, which installs the opencv4.1.0. In the command line, I type `import cv2`, resulting in the `ImportError:DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found`.

Answer (score 0):

Using pip command fixes the problem: `pip install opencv-contrib-python`